# Assigning a value to struct member through reflection in Go

Tags: dictionary, reflection, struct, go

I have a struct v with members A, B, C string. Using reflection, I can get the names of the fields and their values:

```
typ := v.Type()
for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
    // gets us a StructField
    fi := typ.Field(i)
    fieldname := fi.Name
    fmt.Println(fieldname)
    val := fmt.Sprintf("%v", v.Field(i).Interface())
 }
```

since I have the name, and can get the value OUT, can I assign new values to the fields? I would like to do essentially:

```
v.Field(fieldname).Interface() = "new value"
```

but that obviously doesn't work. Is it possible to assign a value into a struct if you only know the name of the field?

In practice, I'm trying to assign values from a `map[string]string` to corresponding fields in a struct, where the struct and map definitions may expand of change over time, and the map may contain more, or less, values than the struct. I've considered doing it w/JSON, but that approach leaves me a little cold, seeing as how easy it was to use reflection to get "almost" there!

Thanks,
Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

**Introduction**

Since you want to access and modify the value of a variable (or field), you need to use the [`reflect.Value`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) type instead of [`reflect.Type`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type). You can acquire it with [`reflect.ValueOf()`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf). Also in order to modify it with reflection, you need to pass the address (a pointer) of the `struct` or value you want to modify (else you could only read it but not modify it).

But you don't want to modify the address/pointer but the *pointed* value, so you have to "navigate" from the `Value` of the pointer to the `Value` of the pointed variable (struct), this is what [`Value.Elem()`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem) is for. It looks like this: `reflect.ValueOf(&s).Elem()`

You can get the `Value` of a struct field with the [`Value.FieldByName()`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.FieldByName) method, which since we passed the address of the pointer to the `ValueOf()` function will be *settable*.

**The Code**

The code is much simpler than the introduction once you understand it. You can also try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/dclLzinFok):

```
var s struct {
    A, B, C string
}
s.A, s.B, s.C = "a1", "b2", "c3"

fmt.Println("Before:  ", s)

v := reflect.ValueOf(&s).Elem()

v.FieldByName("A").SetString("2a")
v.FieldByName("B").SetString("2b")
v.FieldByName("C").SetString("2c")

fmt.Println("After:   ", s)

// Using a map:
m := map[string]string{"A": "ma", "B": "mb", "C": "mc"}
for mk, mv := range m {
    v.FieldByName(mk).SetString(mv)
}

fmt.Println("From Map:", s)
```

Output:

```
Before:   {a1 b2 c3}
After:    {2a 2b 2c}
From Map: {ma mb mc}
```

I recommend to read this blog post to learn the basics of the reflection in Go:

[**The Laws of Reflection**](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection)